# Deleted the authorized_keys file and got into a problem

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I was trying to send files from machine A to machine B.

For that, I created a public-private key pair using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` in machine A. Then I sent the `id_rsa.pub` file to machine B and I added that to the `authorized_keys` file there.

It was working fine while sending from machine A to B, I was not being prompted for the password.

While doing some other experiments with this I accidently deleted the `authorized_keys` file. Now again when I started the above procedure its not working. How to recover that? I am also interested to know is it possible to send files both ways round without being prompted for password?

Comment: Use `ssh-copy-id` after deleting your **authorized_keys** file. Do you still have problems?

Comment: Usually the problem is invalid permissions on the `authorized_files` or the `.ssh` directory or the home directory. See the “troubleshooting” section in the [tag wiki](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/ssh/info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something wrong in your newly created `authorized_keys`.

1. Check the permissions, the recommended permissions are read/write
   for the user, and not accessible by others.
2. Check that you don't
       have extra line breaks in the file and that the key in it actually
       matches the (correct) public key of A.

Note that you don't need to recreate the key pair.

If you want to have public key access from B to A, just replicate the process (create keys in B, move pub to A and add to authorized_keys in there).

Note that public key authorization is the way to identify `client` to `server`. In order to be able to use B as a client, you need to have `sshd` running in A.

Of course you can use `scp` from A also to transfer files from the server B to A without a password, if that was what you ment by "send files both way round without being prompted for password": `scp serverB:filename .`